Discord Chatbot: ClientConnectorCertificateError: Unable to Verify SSL Certificate
Good Morning,
I have been stuck with connecting my disord bot. I have been using PyCharm IDE in attempt to connect my discord bot using the code I created.
My code is looking for the BOT_TokenA and Bot_TokenF's variables that I have stored to initialize in discord for the functionality.
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json
import os
import decouple
from discord.ext import commands
from decouple import config


#decouple is used in this line| Grabds data from env file since its considered as variable or source code
BOT_TOKEN1 = config("BOT_TOKENA")
BOT_TOKEN2 = config("BOT_TOKENF")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="Angel ", intents=discord.Intents.all())
    bot.run(BOT_TOKEN1)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Hello! BOT is ready")
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send("BOT is ready!")


BOT_TOKENA=config('BOT_TOKENA')
BOT_TOKENF=config('BOT_TOKENB')


BOT_TOKEN = config('BOT_TOKEN1')
CHANNEL_ID = 1215073255233163286
CHANNEL_ID2 = 0000000000000

Once I debugged my code this is what appeared within the debugger. The file associated with this error was a "connector.py" file which was directly associated with "aiohttp"
    async def _wrap_create_connection(
        self,
        *args: Any,
        req: ClientRequest,
        timeout: "ClientTimeout",
        client_error: Type[Exception] = ClientConnectorError,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> Tuple[asyncio.Transport, ResponseHandler]:
        try:
            async with ceil_timeout(
                timeout.sock_connect, ceil_threshold=timeout.ceil_threshold
            ):
                return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)
        except cert_errors as exc:
            raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
        except ssl_errors as exc:
            raise ClientConnectorSSLError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
        except OSError as exc:
            if exc.errno is None and isinstance(exc, asyncio.TimeoutError):
                raise
            raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc

debugger info from pycharm
exception = {tuple: 3} (<class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError'>, ClientConnectorCertificateError(ConnectionKey(host='discord.com', port=443, is_ssl=True, ssl=True, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None...onError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
0 = {type} <class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError'>
1 = {ClientConnectorCertificateError} ClientConnectorCertificateError(ConnectionKey(host='discord.com', port=443, is_ssl=True, ssl=True, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None...onError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))
2 = {traceback} <traceback object at 0x107f3bb80>
len = {int} 3
exception = {tuple: 3} (<class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError'>, ClientConnectorCertificateError(ConnectionKey(host='discord.com', port=443, is_ssl=True, ssl=True, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None...onError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
client_error = {type} <class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError'>
exception[0] = {type} <class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError'>
exception = {tuple: 3} (<class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError'>, ClientConnectorCertificateError(ConnectionKey(host='discord.com', port=443, is_ssl=True, ssl=True, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None...onError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
args = {tuple: 3} (functools.partial(<class 'aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler'>, loop=<_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=True debug=False>), '162.159.136.232', 443)
kwargs = {dict: 6} {'family': <AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 'flags': <AddressInfo.AI_NUMERICHOST|AI_NUMERICSERV: 4100>, 'local_addr': None, 'proto': 6, 'server_hostname': 'discord.com', 'ssl': <ssl.SSLContext object at 0x107f168d0>}
req = {ClientRequest} <aiohttp.client_reqrep.ClientRequest object at 0x106a352e0>
self = {TCPConnector} <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x107e61220>
timeout = {ClientTimeout} ClientTimeout(total=300, connect=None, sock_read=None, sock_connect=None, ceil_threshold=5)
client_error = {type} <class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError'>
What would I need to implement to have my code not show this error and connect my client to discord.com?
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')]
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

If you can't figure out how to install certificates properly for Python, then try certifi: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#example-use-certifi

For MacOS in terminal enter lines below,
In terminal code,
"pip install certif"
"/Applications/Python\ 3.12/Install\ Certificates.command"(pay attention to your version of python 3.12 could change depending on what is in your system)

The second line was used to create the correct permission so the network request can be made with the correct SSL requirements.
